# Excel Conditional Formatting - 'IF' Formula Syntax

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula, conditional-formatting

I would like to use this formula as a conditional formatting formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(AccountsMonthsOrdered[Account],'Account Summary 2013'!$A$1,AccountsMonthsOrdered[Month],'Account Summary 2013'!F$12)>0,1,0)
```

It checks to see if the account name $A$1 and month F$12 appear together in the AccountsMonthsOrdered table, returning 1 if it does, and 0 if it does.

It works fine when it's in a cell on its own, but no matter how I try to rephrase it Excel won't accept it in the conditional formatting formula box.

Comment: in CF you don't really need an IF function, just the test, so instead of `=IF(test,1,0)` you can use simply `=test` - other than that K_B's answer should do what you want - which version of Excel are you using....because in some versions (2007 for example) you can't refer to other sheets in CF either.....

Comment: I ended up using the formula  =COUNTIFS(AccountRange,$A$1,MonthRange,F$12)=0  and that seems to do the job. Excel 2007.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula in conditional formatting does not accept Table columns... To remedy make a named range that points to the [Account] column from your table, reference the named range in your formula instead of to the table column. Same for [Month]

Comment: Switched to named ranges and some other tweaking and it seems to work so thanks.  :)